# Why doesn't A <= B <= C work in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

So my coworker got mad at me today because I used a double-bounded inequality in VB.NET. Why wouldn't it work? Basically, the value blnConditionMet is ALWAYS returning true. Even when dr.Item("Value") is not between 400 and 499.

```
        For Each dr As DataRow In dtTable.Rows

            If (400 <= dr.Item("Value") AndAlso dr.Item("Value") <= 499)  Then

                blnConditionMet = True
                Exit For

            End If

        Next
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to check in your if statement?

Comment: The titel suggests you wrote something like `400 <= dr.Item("Value") <= 499` but I don't see that coming back anywhere in your question. In fact, what is your question?

Comment: Doesn't `dr.Item("Value")` return object?

Comment: no, this is not possibile. debug and check `dr.Item("Value")` or your declaration of `blnConditionMet`: maybe its default value is `True`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat way to see what's happening:

Write `Option Strict On` at the very start of the file you're working on.

You will see the compiler error pop up `Option Strict On disallows conversions from Boolean to Integer`.

In other words, when you write `a <= b <= c`, the compiler does **NOT** read it as two integer comparisons. Instead, it reads it as `(a <= b) <= c`.

The condition `(a <= b)` evaluates to a boolean that (unless Option Strict is on!) will automatically and implicitly convert to `0` or `-1`. Then either `0 <= 499` or `-1 <= 499` evaluates to `True`, and this is why the `Then` block always executes.

That is why your coworker got mad and fixed the condition to `a <= b AndAlso b <= c`.

That is, also,  one of the billion reasons why `Option Strict On` should be activated in every single VB.Net program. (You can toggle it in the project properties so you don't have to add the line at the start of every file.)

EDIT: Correction: `True` in VB.Net actually evaluates to `-1` for historical reasons.